# Package `Versions' Warning: Redefining environment

Tags: environments, warnings, versions

I am using the versions.sty package and would like to process some text twice (or more times) in a different version configuration, but within the same document.  So I use `\excludeversion` and `\includeversion` several times.  Each use of these seems to define the environment with the same parameter as the name of the argument.  So I get an annoying warning at every run, cluttering my LaTeX messages.

Here is a small example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{versions}

\begin{document}

\includeversion{A}
\excludeversion{B}

\begin{A}a\end{A}
\begin{B}b\end{B}

\excludeversion{A}
\includeversion{B}

\begin{A}a\end{A}
\begin{B}b\end{B}

\end{document}
```

Produces the following warnings:

```
Package `Versions' Warning: Redefining environment `A' on input line 11.
Package `Versions' Warning: Redefining environment `B' on input line 12.
```

And the following output:

```
a
b
```

The output is fine. Is there a better way of doing what I am trying to achieve without this warnings?

(of course the idea is that the text that is repeated in MWE is included from the same file, so I obtain different run of latex over the same file).

Comment: You can either suppress the warnings, or try a different approach. Which do you want? Everybody may not be familiar with the [`versions` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/versions). Could you provide the expected output of your minimal example?

Comment: @Werner, I believe that it was an MWE already :) but I made it a tad more concrete. I would like best way to achieve multiple runs over the same sub-document, in different versions. Supressing warnings is much less interesting, unless any other alternative is awfully complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can suppress the warnings issued by [`versions`](http://ctan.org/pkg/versions) by adding the following to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\let\@Vs@envwarn\@gobble% Remove environment renewal warnings.
\makeatother
```

Alternatively the [`silence` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/silence) does something similar:

```
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{`Versions'}{Redefining environment}
```

A different approach that uses `\if`-constructions would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\ifVersionA
\newif\ifVersionB
\begin{document}

\VersionAtrue% Include Version A
\VersionBfalse% Exclude Version B

\ifVersionA a \fi
\ifVersionB b \fi

\VersionAfalse% Exclude Version A
\VersionBtrue% Include Version B

\ifVersionA a \fi
\ifVersionB b \fi

\end{document}
```